# Finding out IP what made last reboot on Linux

Tags: linux, ip, reboot

Hello there I'm trying to find out who made last reboot on my server.

I know commands `last reboot | head -1` and `last -d reboot` but they don't show IP from what client IP it was done.

I have Linux CentOS7 server.

I know it's kinda difficult to find, but maybe someone can help, I don't have now any ideas.

Regards

Comment: If it was done over `ssh` look in `auth.log` to see who was logged in around that time.

Comment: It's the problem I was logged and someone else at the same time and I didn't knew that and that "someone" made `reboot`... and I want to know which IP he have

Comment: IIRC that file tells you the IPs of whoever logs in.

Comment: :thinking: which tool you suggest to use? Hard to find something about IIRC tools

Comment: I found that in `/log/var/` I don't have `auth.log` - I read about that all is passed to `/var/log/secure` but there I couldn't even `grep reboot` anything

Comment: "IIRC" means "if I recall correctly"

Answer (score 2):

If the server was rebooted by a logged in user `last | less` command will give you a history of people logged into the machine, time of log in and the IP of the connecting device. Search for a time that the server was rebooted and check who was logged in at that time.

If there were multiple users logged in at that time and you have root access you can check `.bash_history` files in the profile directories (for CentOS should be found somewhere in `/home` e.g if your server is part of a domain /home/domain/username ).

If you're greping for a "reboot" command specifically I'd also note that `shutdown -r` also reboots the server so don't be caught out.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to track first users, who issued `reboot` command, which can be done using linux `audit` system. See the answers [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/336217/how-do-i-log-every-command-executed-by-a-user) for details. Then, when you know the user name, you can proceed to tracking IP.